# JSON C# Classes

Tags: c#, json, rest, class, json-deserialization

I am building a C# integration tool, but I am having some trouble figuring out if I should create different classes for the data that I am receiving from different requests from the source application using REST. The responses are similar in a way that the constructs are the same, but for different information. I.e they would have an "Attributes" tag, but the attributes may vary per class. In the same breath, about 60% or more of the attributes are the same.

It looks like they reused the same constructs, but depending on the data, there are may be more things in the result.

My question is, what is the best practice when creating the classes for the JSON Deserialisation? Do you create multiple classes with the same name and same content(diff namespaces), or do you combine the classes into a "Generic" data type and just include the "extra" attributes, even though they wont all be used by one object.

The assumption is that the "null" values will not be considered in the deserialisation. Thus "extra" fields defined will just be ignored if not found.

The problem comes in the Classes where I would like to be able to define DataType1 and DataType2, but when combining the classes this becomes a problem...

Would like to hear your thoughts :)

Rgs,
Francois

Comment: You don't need different namespaces. In this scenario consider using inheritance. Inherit all common fields from a base class and override them when names are the same but data types are different.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to deserialize in generic classes (lists and dictionaries or whatever your deserialization library offers) and then manually copy the data to whatever further data structures I use internally. Most of the time the "deserialization classes" really are used just for deserialization and the after that the data is immediately copied to further data structures that don't match the deserialization structures. So there's very little value to them.